Why are officers still stamping even though stamps are not applied when going through the automated emigration gates at BKK airport?
As I exited Thailand last month via BKK airport after some conference in Bangkok, I attempted to use the eGates at BKK instead of going through immigration officers. That didn't work and I was told to through an immigration officer, who told me that they must put an exit stamp on passengers' passports, unlike the eGates.
Why do immigration officers place an exit stamp on the passenger's passport while automated emigration gates don't at BKK airport? Assume that the passenger is in good standing, e.g. didn't overstay.
Note:

Thailand state that all passengers, including foreigners, can use the eGates on exit. So we're not in a situation of "They had to put a stamp so I had to see an officer because the eGate can't do it". We don't know the reason why it didn't work through the eGate, but assume that it is not because a stamp was required.

If I had successfully gone through the eGate (which I should be able to), I would not have received a stamp.


The question is not:

"Why did I have to see an officer?"
"Why can't eGates add a stamp?"

The question is: Why for a given passenger that should be able to either use the eGates or see an officer, if they use the eGates they don't get a stamp, and if they see an officer, they do get one?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Reddit user Present-Alfalfa-2507 gave the following answer:

Automated gates give a digital exit stamp in the system, manual gets a physical stamp.

which is echoed by swissed641985

The stamp is digital, not physical.


This is not really an answer. "Digital stamp" is not a stamp. What prevents the human beings from creating digital stamps? Neither of these quotes address the question you were asking, that on top of being basically links to a reddit thread.

@littleadv sounds like you understood the question, so why did you vote to close as needs details or clarity? What shall I clarify?

I understood the question, I just don't care for it. "Why machine can't do things humans can" is not a question worth answering.

@littleadv "I just don't care for it" is not a reason to close.

Thank you for your input, apparently at least 5 people disagree.

@littleadv no, the others, or at least most of them, claim that the question needs details or clarity.

So do I. As I said, "Why machine can't do things humans can" is not a question worth answering. Can you provide details that make it on topic and worth answering? It's a rhetorical question, you don't have to continue trolling me.

@littleadv why do human stamps?

@littleadv that was not the question. You are missing a bit of context which is that the same people can go through the eGates or see an officer. It just happens that this time the eGate did not work for Franck (but it should have). If he had been able to use the eGate (which he should), he would not have gotten a stamp. So the question is not "why do eGates not stamp", which everybody understands is obvious, and not either "why do I have to see an officer" but rather "why do officers continue to stamp, when the stamp is apparently unnecessary since the eGates do not do it".

@jcaron that's not what franck asked though. See the actual question in the second to last sentence of his post.

@littleadv While it's missing the context and is maybe not as explicit as it could be, "Why do immigration officers place an exit stamp on the passenger's passport while automated emigration gates don't at BKK airport?" IMHO clearly asks precisely that. I have edited the question to hopefully make Franck's question more explicit, I hope I haven't betrayed his intentions.

@jcaron thanks for the edit, this is exactly what I was trying to ask.
